# Extract the numbers at the end from a file name using perl

Tags: perl

I am unable to extract the last **digits** in the filename and rename the file placing the digits at the beginning of the file. 
Like suppose my file name is `"Gen_TCC_TIF_2110_413010_L3TL_Ae6TL707285_371925.out"`
I want to rename the file as `"371925_Gen_TCC_TIF_2110_413010_L3TL_Ae6TL707285.out"`

```
my $newFileName ='Gen_TCC_TIF_2110_413010_L3TL_Ae6TL707285_371925.out';
my ($digits) = $newFileName =~ /(\d+)/g;
my $newFileName_2="${digits}_Gen_TCC_TIF_2110_413010_L3TL_Ae6TL707285_371925.out"
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it with a single regex:

```
my $newFileName = 'Gen_TCC_TIF_2110_413010_L3TL_Ae6TL707285_371925.out';
my $newFileName_2 = $filename =~ s/(.*)_(\d+)(?=\.out)/$2_$1/r;
# or, for older Perl, use this instead:
(my $newFileName_2 = $filename) =~ s/(.*)_(\d+)(?=\.out)/$2_$1/;
# or, to modify directly the variable $newFileName:
$newFileName =~ s/(.*)_(\d+)(?=\.out)/$2_$1/;
```

Or if you want to get the digits (because you need them for something else), then you can do:

```
my ($digits) = $newFileName =~ /_(\d+)\.out/;
```

You were using `/g` modifier, which made your regex match all blocks of digits, which isn't what you wanted. (even worst, it was returning an array, but you were only keeping the first element (`2110`) in the scalar `$digit` )

Comment: Anything wrong with my answer? (to explain the downvote)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 $newFileName =~ /(\d+)\.out/;
my $digits = $1;
my $newFileName_2=$digits."_Gen_TCC_TIF_2110_413010_L3TL_Ae6TL707285_371925.out";
```

`(\d+)\.out/` should give you all Digits before `.out`

Comment: I only require to extract the digits before .out , like in this case I want 371925

Comment: @s12, that is what `$newFileName =~ /(\d+)\.out/;`do

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$newFileName =~ s/(.*?)_(\d+)\.out/$2_$1\.out/;
```

Or

```
$newFileName =~ s/(.*?)_(\d+)(\.\w+)/$2_$1$3/;
```